# [android]how to get 4 buttons at the bottom and each 2 button is beside each other

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I find majority teaching online is about 2 button beside each other but I couldnt obtain the arrangement wanted as in the image. When I put in the relativelayout, all the button overlap together no matter I put android:layout_above:"XX" All my total, 0.00, back and pay button , i need to out them at the bottom. this is my original code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/billTV"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/backB"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Back" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/payB"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Pay" />
</LinearLayout>
```

[image: My bill layout]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/billTV"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.55"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/total"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/backB"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Back" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/payB"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Pay" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Try some thing like this.

Comment: Thanks! Mind explain why layout_weight = 0.55 do the tricks? I hope I can solve something like this in the future. =)

Comment: Actually layout weight is used to give relative size for your view accordance to the screen size, just like we are giving a height and width in percentage.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/billTV"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="394dp"
                android:text="TextView" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/total"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="32dp"
                android:text="TextView" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/backB"
                android:layout_width="106dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Back" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/payB"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Pay" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

try this