# Android Button positioning

Tags: android, button

In android I have four different buttons. I set two button horizontally side by side by using android:layout_weight="1". When i did this another two buttons came aside the previous two buttons. I want to make a group of another two button horizontally just bottom of the previous two buttons.How I can do this??
I am using Eclipse(Hilious) and Android 2.3.3 
Here is my xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">


    <Button
    android:layout_width="20px" 
    android:text="Second Activity" 
    android:id="@+id/button1" 
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </Button>

    <Button 
    android:layout_width="20px" 
    android:text="Third Activity" 
    android:id="@+id/button2" 
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </Button>


    <Button
     android:id="@+id/button3" 
     android:layout_width="20px" 
     android:layout_weight="1"
     android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
     android:text="Fourth Activity">
     </Button>

    <Button 
    android:id="@+id/button4" 
    android:layout_width="20px" 
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="Fifth Activity">
    </Button>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: could you please show us your xml code?

Comment: its better if you show us some layout design which type of design you want or simple paint.

Comment: go from below link it may be help ful to you [demo][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9807778/androidhow-to-get-4-buttons-at-the-bottom-and-each-2-button-is-beside-each-oth

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9807778/androidhow-to-get-4-buttons-at-the-bottom-and-each-2-button-is-beside-each-oth

Comment: you want 2 button in first row and another 2 button in 2nd row..??

Answer (score 2):

Please try this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1" >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
       android:text="Btn1" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Btn2" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1" >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Btn3" />
   <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Btn4" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use two layouts like this

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">


        <Button
        android:layout_width="20px" 
        android:text="Second Activity" 
        android:id="@+id/button1" 
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </Button>

        <Button 
        android:layout_width="20px" 
        android:text="Third Activity" 
        android:id="@+id/button2" 
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </Button>

    </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
        <Button
         android:id="@+id/button3" 
         android:layout_width="20px" 
         android:layout_weight="1"
         android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
         android:text="Fourth Activity">
         </Button>

        <Button 
        android:id="@+id/button4" 
        android:layout_width="20px" 
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="Fifth Activity">
        </Button>

    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Second Activity" >
    </Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Third Activity" >
    </Button>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Fourth Activity" >
    </Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Fifth Activity" >
    </Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

check this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="20px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Second Activity" >
        </Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="20px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Third Activity" >
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="20px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Fourth Activity" >
        </Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="20px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Fifth Activity" >
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```